# Pass Domain Object into service for creation of data - class now found error?

Tags: class, grails, service, compiler-construction

I currently have a Grails app that has a service that I want to call whenever I want to add new data to the database. The code below shows the service code:

```
def domainSave( domainData, domain ){

        new domain(domainData).save(flush: true)

    }
```

and this is how I will be calling it:

```
MyService.domainSave(it, Users)
```

Now what I want to do is have a service that I can call to create new data i the domain. However the grails app wont compile as where I have "new domain" it is unable to resolve that class at compile time as the qualified class isn't in there yet.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

this doesn't work of course

You need to use a reflection for that:

```
def domainSave( domainData, Class clazz ){
    def domain = clazz.newInstance()
    domain.properties = domainData
    domain.save flush:true
}
```